# Looking for direction on a pouchdb error

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

```
error:"unauthorized"
id:"_design/db"
message:"You are not a db or server admin."
name:"unauthorized"
ok:true
reason:"You are not a db or server admin."
rev:"137-81fe83389359c1cfb50bf928f3558b81"
status:500
```

Pouchdb is trying to push a design document, after a full uninstall/reinstall of the app (so the local pouchdb should have been erased).  I am guessing this is in the change stream somewhere.  But the weird part is the couchdb is on revision 133, not 137.

How do I fix this?  I tried a compact but that didn't work.  Only obvious answer I can think of is manually make a bunch of revisions to the design on couch, so that it's newer than 137.

I ran a search on the changes stream using this code

```
var http=require('http');
var url = "http:/server/db/_changes?style=all_docs";
http.get(url, function(res){
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
        var test = JSON.parse(body);
        test.results.forEach(function(item,index){
            if (item.id==="_design/db"){
                console.log(item);
            }
        });
    });
}).on('error', function(e){
    console.log("Got an error: ", e);
});
```

And got 1 result, rev 133, the correct one.  So where is pouchdb getting this from?

--Edit
Deleting the *pouch* database seems to fix it until the next app install.

Comment: As far as I know, `unauthorized` means that you have to provide an admin username/password?

Comment: It's really just because the phone has some future version of the design doc, which it has no permission to push back to couch.  But it seems like Android specifically is somehow restoring this future version every time the app is installed.

Comment: @user3405291 I've partially issolated the problem to Android 7.1.  On app upgrade or uninstall, cordova is no longer using the webview (no idea what it uses instead).  Whatever it is using is keeping all cookies, pouchdb, IndexDB, and some offline storage.  SQLlite does appear to be removed but I am testing that thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

The error status code is `500` which based on [the documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/basics.html#http-status-codes) is:

> 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> The request was invalid, either because the supplied JSON was invalid,
>   or invalid information was supplied as part of the request.

Also, the error message and reason mention that:

> message:"You are not a db or server admin."
>
> reason:"You are not a db or server admin."

---

I think the error might be caused by database admin and member  permissions. Because, ordinary database **member** users/roles cannot PUT design docs, only database **admin** users/roles can PUT design docs:

[image]

---

You mentioned that:

> It's really just because the phone has some future version of the
>   design doc ...

If there is a problem with revision, there should be received a `409 - Conflict` error NOT a `500 - Internal Server Error`.

---

I'm not sure, just an idea.

Comment: It's trying to push a future version of the design doc, but as a user that has no permission to do so. So access denied makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out Android now uses google drive to make backups of indexdb.  This was causing the installed version of the app to keep getting a future version of the document after database rollbacks during testing.
The only way around it I found was to do this.

```
.on('denied', function (result) {
    if (result.doc.error === "unauthorized" && result.doc.id === "_design/db") {
        //catastrophic failure
        var DBDeleteRequest = window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase("_pouch_");

        DBDeleteRequest.onerror = function (event) {
            console.error("Error deleting database.");
            throw new Error("Error deleting database.");
        };

        DBDeleteRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
            console.log("Database deleted successfully");
            window.location.reload(); //reload the app after purge
        };
    }
}
```

Even a pouchdb.destroy would not fully clear the problem.  It's a bit of a nuke from orbit solution.